# MySQL LOAD JSON with Line Breaks produces error

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL (version 5.7.21) DB with 2 columns:
`id` is a simple auto-increment field INT(11)
and `jsondata` is a JSON object field.

The JSON I need to import looks like this:

```
{
   "archive": "0iHBvqAX-2017-12-10T23:15:06",
   "barchive": "0iHBvqAX-2017-12-10T23:15:06",
   "id": "698fd4fd641a211fb569f704ee114f9829505a567ebc85502ea030705038600b",
   "name": "0iHBvqAX-2017-12-10T23:15:06",
   "start": "2017-12-10T23:15:08.000000",
   "time": "2017-12-10T23:15:08.000000"
}
```

This is my MySQL Import:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.json' INTO TABLE thetable(jsondata);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Missing a name for object member." at position 1 in value for column 'thetable.jsondata'.
```

Now, if we remove all the returns like this:

```
{ "archive": "0iHBvqAX-2017-12-10T23:15:06",   "barchive": "0iHBvqAX-2017-12-10T23:15:06",   "id": "698fd4fd641a211fb569f704ee114f9829505a567ebc85502ea030705038600b",   "name": "0iHBvqAX-2017-12-10T23:15:06",   "start": "2017-12-10T23:15:08.000000",   "time": "2017-12-10T23:15:08.000000" }
```

The import works perfect. Is there a way to tell MySQL to ignore the `\n` in the JSON file?

Comment: There may be other invisible control characters around those newlines. You can check by printing out charcode for each character.

Comment: it's only a `\n` unix line break

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. It's not the answer you're looking for, but I used grep in linux to remove unwanted characters.